# How to use external data file in Bokeh standalone HTML (no Bokeh server)

Tags: html, file, bokeh, external

I want to use Bokeh on commodity webhosting, where no Bokeh server is available. Is there a way to create a Bokeh standalone html file, that can access an external data file (such as CSV or JSON) and use that data?

This way, a user can update the data file (for example upload a new CSV file), and the Bokeh data visualization wil use this updated data automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Bokeh 1.3 [added a new FileInput widget](https://blog.bokeh.org/posts/release-1-3-0). However, it should be noted that a static HTML page can only update in response to an uploaded file while the page is open. There is no way to make any persistent changes based on the file upload (short of calling out to some remote REST API or database). Reloading the page would return it it whatever original state it was in before the upload.